# C# InvokeMember - MissingMethodException: 'Method not found'

Tags: c#, reflection, invokemember, bindingflags

In a .NET Core 6 RestAPI application, I'm tracking global stock exchanges and have an instance of the below Exchange class called "ex".

```
public class Exchange
{
    public string CountryCode { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
    public string DataSourceCode { get; set; }
    public int DaysHoursId { get; set; }
    public string ExchangeCode { get; set; }
    public string ExchangeName { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset LastUpdatedDate { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedStatus { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset NextUpdateDateTime { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Timezone { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public string Website { get; set; }
}
```

All fields are populated with non-null data.  In this case, the body of my Postman call is:
{
"CountryCode": "USA",
"Currency": "USD",
"DataSourceCode": "IA2",
"DaysHoursId": 2,
"ExchangeCode": "AMEX",
"ExchangeName": "AMEX",
"IsActive": true,
"LastUpdatedDate": "2022-04-24T15:42:28.2533333+00:00",
"LastUpdatedStatus": "OK",
"NextUpdateDateTime": "2022-04-24T15:42:28.2533333+00:00",
"Region": "NORTH AMERICA",
"Timezone": "EST",
"Type": "STOCK",
"Url": "https://www.nyse.com/markets/nyse-american",
"Website": "www.AMEX.com"
}

Using Reflection, I create a DataTable from this object with all columns except for "Id", which is an Identity primary key in the table to which data will be loaded, as follows:

```
 PropertyDescriptorCollection props = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(ex);
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 foreach (PropertyDescriptor p in props)
 {
      if (p.Name != "Id")  // insert into an identity column not allowed.
      { 
           dt.Columns.Add(p.Name, p.PropertyType);
      }
 }
```

I then attempt to create a row in the dt datatable, as follows:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
Type t = ex.GetType();
for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    t.InvokeMember(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, ex, new object[] { dt.Columns[i].ColumnName });
}
```

... which, when executed and traced, InvokeMember successfully iterated through the CountryCode, Currency, and DataSourceCode columns, but then - when it reaches DaysHoursId - threw a "System.MissingMethodException: 'Method MarketApi.Core.Entitites.Exchange.DaysHoursId' not found' exception.

Any insight as to what I'm doing wrong would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I would assume that it's failing on that property because the value you're passing is a `string`. The previous properties are all type `string` so assigning a column name to them will work. That property is type `int` though, so you need to pass an `int` value to assign to it, not a `string`.

Comment: @John - In the above Postman call, I am passing an integer value of 2.  Is this what you meant?

Comment: When you call `t.InvokeMember`, the last argument you provide, i.e. `new object[] { dt.Columns[i].ColumnName }` is an array of values to pass to the invoked member. Because you're invoking a property setter, that means that the element of that array is the value being assigned to the property. You are passing `dt.Columns[i].ColumnName` and expecting that to be assigned to an `int` property.

Answer (score 0):

It throws for *DaysHoursId*  because it is the first non-string Property of your class Exchange.
The problem is that you set the property *names* also as their *values*.

Works for *CountryCode, Currency, DataSourceCode*, that expect each a string value. But crashes on *DaysHoursId*. The binder looks for a string property setter method of name/signature `set_DaysHoursId(string)` which actually doesn't exist.

You rather want to assign the values in that loop:

```
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
Type t = ex.GetType();
//TODO fill your data in here
object [] values = new [dt.Columns.Count] { /* "de", "EUR", ... */};

for (int i = 0; i <= dt.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    t.InvokeMember(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, ex, 
                  new [] { values [i] });
}
```